# Domain of $f(x)=\frac {\sqrt{x^2-1}} {x-10}$.

Tags: calculus, real-numbers

Let's say I have this function: $f(x)=\frac {\sqrt{x^2-1}} {x-10}$.

Now, I want to find the domain.

- For the square root I find $\mathbb{R} - ]-1;1[$.
- For the denominator I find $\mathbb{R} - \{10\}$.

What is the correct way to combine both the elements with the "$\mathbb{R} - \dots$" notation?

Comment: Have you tried expressing the domain as a union of intervals?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you mean that the correct notation is $\mathbb{R} - ]-1;1[  \cup \{ 10 \}$ ?

Comment: No.  Please see the comments left by the user NeitherNor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using set subtraction notation, then something like this
$$\mathbb{R}-\{(-1,1)\cup \{10\}\}$$

Answer (score 1):

The domain is $(-\infty,-1) \cup (1,10) \cup (10,\infty)$

Comment: Could you explain it?

Comment: No, this is not the answer I was searching for, I would like to have a R- something notation.

Comment: Should be $(\infty,-1]\cup[1,10)\cup(10,\infty)$.

Comment: Or $\mathbb{R}\setminus((-1,1)\cup\{10\})$

Comment: @NeitherNor so is it correct to say that $ ( ) $ can be used both for non-including in a range and for grouping?

Comment: @albertopasqualetto I would say so. It's not the nicest notation, but it's still rather clear and I don't see a better one.

Comment: @NeitherNor thanks!